# Installing repo into linux by using create repo command , create command not found

Tags: linux, packages, repository

I just want to create my repo but it is not working use the command

```
create repo -v "foldername"
```

but it showing

```
bash :create:command not found
```

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3):

On the assumption you're trying to create a `yum` repo, you need to run:

```
yum install createrepo
```

and then the command is:

```
createrepo
```

WITHOUT a space between `create` and `repo`.

See [here](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoCreate) for more information.

Comment: There is a faster version now called `createrepo_c`.

http://rpm-software-management.github.io/createrepo_c/